# Visual Studio 2019 : Cannot change Runtime Library : Error "Element <RuntimeLibrary> has an invalid value of /MDd "

Tags: c, compilation, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio to compile a C code and I would like to change the Runtime Library paramater (which can be found in Project Property -> Code generation -> Runtime library). At first it was working when I did not change anything. Now, even if I go back to "/MDd" or "(/MDd)" or other funny things I tried containing the /MDd thing, I get the Error :

```
Element <RuntimeLibrary> has an invalid value of /MDd
```

What should I type? I know this must be obvious but I couldn't find the answer out there...
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.vcxproj` file does not hold the compiler flag directly, instead the valid `<RuntimeLibrary>` values are:

```
<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebugDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
```

In the Visual Studio properties window, use the drop down, don't "type" a value as you can enter invalid values.